# How I get the Context with guice in provider?

Tags: android, guice, roboguice

How I get the Context? Am I doing something wrong here?

This is my Error in Android:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
        1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public class DatabaseProvider implements Provider {

    @Inject
    protected static Provider<Context> contextProvider;
    //eror context is null
    protected Context context = contextProvider.get();

    @Override
    public DatabaseHelper get() {
        return (DatabaseHelper) OpenHelperManager
            .getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class);
    }
}
```

Implement DaoProvider:

```
public class DaoProvider<D extends Dao<E, ?>, E> implements Provider<D> {

@Inject
private DatabaseProvider databaseProvider;


private final Class<E> cls;

public DaoProvider(Class<E> cls) {
    this.cls = cls;
}

@Override
public D get() {

    try {
        return databaseProvider.get().getDao(cls);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.d("injection", "database provider error", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Implement in module:

```
public class BabyModule extends AbstractModule {
@Override
protected void configure() {

        TypeLiteral<Dao<Baby, Integer>> typeLiteral = new TypeLiteral<Dao<Baby,         Integer>>(){};
        DaoProvider<Dao<Baby,Integer>, Baby> provider = new DaoProvider<Dao<Baby,Integer>, Baby>(Baby.class);
        bind(typeLiteral).toProvider(provider);
}
```

}

Thanks for help

Comment: Any `@Inject` do not happen until _after_ the constructor was run.

Comment: What do you mean constructor?

Comment: The object cannot be analysed for what to inject until _after_ it has been fully created.  Hence the `contextProvider.get()` is being run before the contextProvder is set by Guice.

Comment: Would you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Delay asking for the Context until you actually _need_ it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have my own solution. I get my context about the application.class now.

```
public class DatabaseHelperProvider implements Provider<DatabaseHelper> {

    @Inject
    Application application;

    @Override
    public DatabaseHelper get() {

    return OpenHelperManager
            .getHelper(application.getApplicationContext(), DatabaseHelper.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using

`@Inject Context context`

instead of

`@Inject
 protected static Provider<Context> contextProvider; 
 //eror context is null

 protected Context context = contextProvider.get();`

should solve your problem. If it doesn´t why you just don´t access the context lazy...

Comment: I had already tried. What do you mean?  If it doesn´t why you just don´t access the context lazy...

Answer (score -1):

better:

```
@Override
public DatabaseHelper get(Context context) {
     return (DatabaseHelper) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DatabaseHelper.class);
}
```

You can tak context from activity (Activity is extending Context).

Comment: I call this in module to. About AbstractModule from guice.

Comment: if you change the method signature, then it's not overriding the same method

Comment: So you have to get context in constructor - passing it as a parameter of constructor.